# Spring : Command object not getting populated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two controllers , a simple form controller and a multiaction controller.

Now, in simpleformcontroller, i want to redirect a request to multiaction controller.

Here's code snippet in simpleformcontroller

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) {
MyObject myOb = (MyObject )command;
system.out.println(myOb.toString);
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("another.htm"));
mav.addObject("Obj",myOb);
return mav;
}
```

another.htm binds to a method in multiaction controller.

```
<bean id="MyController" class="MyController">
<property name="methodNameResolver">
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
                <property name="mappings">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="/another.htm">another</prop>
                    </props>
        </property>
  </bean>
</bean>
```

and the code in multiactioncontroller is

```
public class MyController extends MultiActionController {
    public ModelAndView another(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, MyObject myObj)   {
        system.out.println(myObj.toString());

}


}
```

The output is, all fields of Myobj are nulls in mutiactioncontroller whereas they have valid values when passed in simpleformcontroller.

Am i missing something here or is this not the right way to pass command objects ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `SimpleFormController` and `MultiActionController`? They're obsolete and a pain to use, and long since replaced with annotated controllers.

Comment: This is a legacy code and we need to use it. Thats the history behind it

Comment: [Here's an example](http://www.earldouglas.com/node/16) that might help steer you in the right direction. It uses annotated controllers, which have effectively replaced the old-style controllers that you are attempting to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unless** you store your MyObject in The session, you will always get null. It occurs because The user data *does not survive redirect*. To store your command object in The session, use [setSessionForm](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractFormController.html#setSessionForm(boolean)) in The SimpleFormController and Then retrieve your command by using

```
public ModelAndView another(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session, MyObject myObj) throws CRPMException  {
```

instead